# error while consuming a .Net web service from a WSDL in NetBeans

Tags: java, .net, web-services, netbeans, jaxb

I have a web service defined in .Net and I want to consume it using java.
When I want to create a web service client from WSDL in NetBeans I get the following error.

Web service client can not be created by JAXWS:wsimport utility.

[ERROR] Property "Any" is already defined. Use <jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.

Here is one part of my WSDL file :

```
    <s:element name="Select_Normal_Response">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Select_Normal_Result">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="..."/>
                        <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="" processContents="lax" />
                    </s:sequence>
                </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="Select_Normal_With_LastIDResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Select_Normal_With_LastIDResult">
                <s:complexType>
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="..."/>
                        <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="..." processContents="lax" />
                    </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

I think because I have two s:any tags, I get this error.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second "s:any" tag has the a Microsoft specific namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" which is non-standard. You can remove the tag from wsdl and retry generating the web service client.

Comment: it generates wsdl automatically, how can i remove?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a binding file to give the second any a unique name.
Create e.g the bindings.xjb file:

```
    <jaxws:bindings
            xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
            jxb:version="2.0"
            xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
            jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
    >
        <jaxws:bindings>
            <jxb:bindings node="/s:element/.../s:any[@namespace='...']">
                <jxb:property name="any2" />
            </jxb:bindings>
        </jaxws:bindings>
    </jaxws:bindings>
```

You can then build the classes using

```
    wsimport "http://www.yourwsdl.com/path?wsdl" -b bindings.xjb
```

If you use maven you can use the jaxws-maven-plugin. Using this will automatically build the client classes when building the project.

e.g.

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <executions>
                    <execution> 
                            <id>webservice</id>
                            <goals> 
                                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                    <packageName>com.company.app.wsclient</packageName>
                                    <wsdlUrls>
                                            <wsdlUrl>http://www.yourwsdl.com/path?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                                    </wsdlUrls>
                                    <bindingFiles>
                                            <string>${basedir}/src/main/resources/bindings.xjb</string>
                                    </bindingFiles>
                            </configuration>
                    </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                            <version>2.2.5</version>
                    </dependency>
            </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```